# Need to migrate Windows Server 2003 for Small Business to Windows Server 2012 R2 Essentials

Tags: windows-server-2012, migration, windows-sbs-2003

I've already found : "[Migrate Windows Small Business Server 2003 to Windows Server 2012 Essentials](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj200112.aspx)" and "[Migrate from Previous Versions to Windows Server 2012 R2 Essentials or Windows Server Essentials Experience](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn408633.aspx)"

I didn't read them yet (I'm going to though). Do you guys have some hands on experience tips that would help us do this project as painless as possible?

There's nothing special about this setup : No exchange, No SQL server. Basically, the important thing would be that each of the 10 users could still login to their account after the migration, without the need top recreate each account individually and without having to redo their user account on each computer. Currently their user profile is stored on each individual computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't forget to transfer all FSMO role.

Don't forget to make it a global catalog.

Don't forget to test your new DC (dcpromo at the minimum)

Don't forget to test your replication (https://redmondmag.com/articles/2014/08/08/repadmin-for-ad-troubleshooting.aspx)

If your SBS2003 is a printserver, advise the users it can be problem on day #1. As the SBS 2003 is 32 bits, and you 2012R2 is x64. Old driver will not work and you might be unable to find matching x86 & x64 driver, thus will lead to new driver. (Please install the printserver role, to give you a *chance* to get the old driver)

From memory you got a 21 days "windows" before closing the source server (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn408635.aspx)

Comment: OK thanks. I'll keep that in mind. Please don't close the question yet, OK?. I might return here for guidance if something comes up. I'd need 1 month maybe.

Comment: We have 10 users. Let's say all I want to keep from the old server is the users. Like, I want all the users to be remembered (so I don't have to reconfigure 10 users on 10 machines), but I want all the other settings to become default or like a fresh install. Is that possible?

Comment: Yes, it's called a migration as the new server will take the role of the old server and copy all user/AD data & SID. thats why you must make sure the migration went well.

Comment: OK. Basically what are the steps to export the users and computers to the new server?

Comment: If it's an AD, you need to join the new server to the domain, user will be migrated in that process

Comment: At your place I would think to hire someone, or ask a real life technician for help  to give guidance. To see how it's build, and to help in the first step of the migration live is a must if you never did it. There is a limit online that we can't see all problem that can happen

Comment: I'm a real life tech. It's my first time. I believe I can do it myself. I just need to get some information first. That's why I'm here asking questions.

Comment: Yeah, I didnt wanted to appear harsh, as in shop where iam, guys can get a mentor for their first time for such move. But yes for your question, AD directy replication will transfert user, computer, and all the active directory database

Comment: It's okay. No offense taken. Having a mentor would be great sometimes. I'm a solo operation so I've kinda managed without one until now. So far so good. Thanks for your help by the way. I'm going to start reading the articles mentioned above.

Comment: At step 2 of this tutorial : "Migrate from Previous Versions to Windows Server 2012 R2 Essentials or Windows Server Essentials Experience" (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn408633.aspx?f=255&mspperror=-2147217396) : They mention to "To install Windows Server Essentials as a replica Windows Server 2012 R2 domain controller in an existing domain". Is this optional or is it mandatory. I mean, if I want the migration to work, I need to set the destination server as a replica?

Comment: Yes, I readed the step, and they mean to integrate the new server to all AD's role

Comment: on the page "Install a Replica Windows Server 2012 Domain Controller in an Existing Domain (Level 200)" (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj574134.aspx) they say : "Run adprep.exe /gpprep manually for all domains that were not previously prepared for Windows Server 2003, Windows Server 2008, or Windows Server 2008 R2. " Does it mean I need to run adprep.exe /gpprep on my source windows 2003 before adding 2012 to the domain?

Comment: 2012 do it by default from memory, else yes in case it does not do it for you. you run adprep on the 2003 with the tool from the 2012 dvd.

Comment: OK thanks. How do I know if it was ran already or not? Does it matter if it's done before I set the destination server as a Replica or after?

Comment: Hi, no, when you add the Active Directory role, it will sync there when you run the wizard..